# Function that accepts only keys of array values (and deduces return type)

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript2.8, conditional-types

I'm trying to grok the new [conditional types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/21316) in typescript 2.8.

For example, I have have some objects with array properties which in my flow must have exactly one element and I want to get this value. 
Here is the [code I thought should work](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20ArrayProperties%3CT%3E%20%3D%20Pick%3CT%2C%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5BK%20in%20keyof%20T%5D%3A%20T%5BK%5D%20extends%20Array%3Cany%3E%3F%20K%20%3A%20never%0D%0A%7D%5Bkeyof%20T%5D%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20obj%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20a%3A%204%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20n%3A%20%5B2%5D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20s%3A%20%5B%22plonk%22%5D%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20single%3CT%2C%20K%20extends%20keyof%20ArrayProperties%3CT%3E%3E(t%3A%20T%2C%20k%3A%20K)%3A%20ArrayProperties%3CT%3E%5BK%5D%5Bnumber%5D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20val%20%3D%20t%5Bk%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(!Array.isArray(val))%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20throw%20new%20Error(%60Expected%20%24%7Bk%7D%20to%20be%20an%20array%60)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(val.length%20!%3D%3D%201)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20throw%20new%20Error(%60Expected%20exactly%20one%20%24%7Bk%7D%60)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20val%5B0%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20n%20%3D%20single(obj%2C%20%22n%22)%3B%20%2F%2F%20'n'%20should%20be%20of%20type%20'number'%0D%0Aconst%20s%20%3D%20single(obj%2C%20%22s%22)%3B%20%2F%2F%20's'%20should%20be%20of%20type%20'string'%0D%0Aconst%20a%20%3D%20single(obj%2C%20%22a%22)%3B%20%2F%2F%20Should%20fail%20to%20compile), it correctly allows only relevant properties to be passed in but I can't figure out how to specify the return type. I get the following compilation error:

> Type `number` cannot be used to index type `Pick<T, { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends any[] ? K : never; }[keyof T]>[K]`.

And the types of `n` and `s` are deduced to be `number|string` rather than `number` for `n` and `string` for `s`.

**Code follows:**

```
type ArrayProperties<T> = Pick<T, {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Array<any>? K : never
}[keyof T]>;

const obj = {
    a: 4,
    n: [2],
    s: ["plonk"]
};

// Compilation error on next line
function single<T, K extends keyof ArrayProperties<T>>(t: T, k: K): ArrayProperties<T>[K][number] {
    const val = t[k];
    if (!Array.isArray(val))
        throw new Error(`Expected ${k} to be an array`);

    if (val.length !== 1) 
        throw new Error(`Expected exactly one ${k}`);

    return val[0];
}

const n = single(obj, "n"); // 'n' should be of type 'number'
const s = single(obj, "s"); // 's' should be of type 'string'
const a = single(obj, "a"); // Should fail to compile (OK)
```

Comment: you cannot use `ArrayProperties<T>[K][number]` as the return type as typescript is not checking the datatype of the elements which are in the array properties for eg. `s: ["plonk"]` here the return type would be a `string` and not a number

Comment: and regarding the type of n,s it's returned as a union type and not a single one.You can use `ArrayProperties<T>[K][any]` or simply `ArrayProperties<T>[K]` it should compile

Comment: @Niladri I thought typescript should deduce the type for each `K` and thus if called with `"n"` then `ArrayProperties<T>["n"]` should be a number array and `ArrayProperty<T>["n"][number]` should be `number`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few workarounds you can use to get this working.

#### To fix the reported error:

To force the TypeScript compiler to look up a property when it can't verify that the property exists, you can intersect the key type with the known keys.  Like this:

```
type ForceLookup<T, K> = T[K & keyof T]; // no error
```

So you can change

```
ArrayProperties<T>[K][number]
```

to

```
ForceLookup<ArrayProperties<T>[K],number>
```

Let's make sure that works:

```
type N = ForceLookup<ArrayProperties<typeof obj>["n"],number>; // number ✔️
type S = ForceLookup<ArrayProperties<typeof obj>["s"],number>; // string ✔️
```

#### to infer narrower types for `n` and `s`:

The problem is that `K` is not being inferred as a string literal.  To hint that the compiler should infer a string literal when possible for a type parameter, you can add the constraint `extends string`.  It is not well-documented, but there are particular situations in which [TypeScript infers literal types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/10676) instead of widening to the more general type (so when `1` is inferred as `1` and not `number`, or when `'a'` is inferred as `'a'` and not `string`).  The contraint `keyof ArrayProperties<T>` apparently does not trigger this non-widening, so `K` is widened to `keyof ArrayProperties<T>` in all cases.  Here's the workaround for `K`:

```
K extends string & keyof ArrayProperties<T>
```

---

Let's see it all in action:

```
declare function single<T, K extends string & keyof ArrayProperties<T>>(
  t: T, k: K): ForceLookup<ArrayProperties<T>[K],number>;
const n = single(obj, "n"); // number ✔️
const s = single(obj, "s"); // string ✔️
const a = single(obj, "a"); // still error ✔️
```

All done!

---

Well, there's a bit of simplification I would do here. `ArrayProperties<T>[K]` can be reduced to `T[K]`, for any `K` that you can actually use.  So you get:

```
declare function single<T, K extends string & keyof ArrayProperties<T>>(
  t: T, k: K): ForceLookup<T[K],number>;
```

All done for real now.

---

Hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: I was on vacation and only now verified that your code works... I have to say this is less than intuitive. Thanks for educating me!